# Pi seems to prevent DVD player from switching on TV automatically

Tags: hdmi

I'm not sure if I'm expecting too much here but here goes ...

My DVD player is connected by HDMI and when I press Play it switches itself on and thereby switches on the TV (Grundig Sydney 4xHDMI) which automatically selects the appropriate HDMI input.

Since I added the Raspberry Pi (set up as an XBMC) this function no longer works - even when the Pi is switched off. If the TV is off and the Pi is already switched on and then the DVD is activated, the TV fires up but shows the Pi screen.

Any ideas what is going on here?

**Clarification**

- As long as the Pi is connected via HDMI to the TV, the DVD player cannot wake the TV at all.
- It makes no difference whether the Pi is powered on or not.
- If the Pi's HDMI cable is unplugged from the TV then the DVD can wake the TV.
- Once the TV is active I can select either of the inputs manually.

Comment: By "even when the Pi is switched off" do you mean the power is plugged, or something else?

Comment: @goldilocks - when the power is removed from the R-Pi but HDMI still connected

Comment: In that case, it is the same thing as if you had an HDMI cable with nothing on one end (or any *completely unpowered* device) and the other plugged into your TV, right?  Implying the issue is with how the TV works... Same WRT when "the TV is off and the Pi is already switched on and then the DVD is activated" -- this implies the TV turns itself on but then cannot decide between two active inputs.  Tell Grundig what it *should* do is detect which input activated it and then use that one.

Comment: I now notice that, so long the Pi is plugged in (power on or not), the DVD cannot wake the TV at all. If I remove the Pi then the DVD does wake the TV :-(

Comment: If the pi is plugged in, the power is ON.  It cannot be turned off; halting the system does not turn the power off (although the HDMI signal does then cut out).

Comment: Actually, here's something interesting I just observed with my (samsung) TV: when I halt the pi but leave it plugged in, after the shutdown the screen clears and there a message "No signal".  That will be there if I turn the TV on and off and select that input.  BUT, if I *unplug* the pi, the message changes to "Check signal cable".  In other words, the TV does register a difference between the pi plugged and unplugged, even if the system on it is not running.

Comment: Sorry it's a bit confusing. When I said 'plugged in' I meant with respect to the HDMI cable!

Comment: Right, so my point is: my TV responds to a dead pi (as in, with the *power* unplugged) on the end of an HDMI cable the same way it would respond to just the HDMI cable with nothing on the other end -- *which is different than no cable on the input*.  So there are at least FOUR implied states for an HDMI input: active, passive, *error* (eg, cable with nothing on it), and null (no cable plugged in). If the third one (cable with nothing on it) does the same thing for you, then it has nothing much to do with the pi at all.

Comment: Consider switching so that the HDMI-port in the tv currently connected to the DVD becomes the one connected to the Raspberry and vice versa.  This might be a question of the TV only supporting HDMI-CEC on the first device found.