# Powerless RPi blocks CEC commands from TV to BD-Player

Tags: hdmi

Setup: RPi B Rev 2 (Archlinux 3.12.20-4) connected to Samsung TV via HDMI. Also connected to the TV is a Samsung Bluray-Player.

Issue: Powering down the RPi disables CEC between TV and BD-Player. That is switching on the BD-Player is not waking up the TV. Commands of the TV (by remote controll) are not transmitted to the BD-Player.

Research: Changing HDMI-Ports on the TV yields no different result. Connecting a HDMI cable to the TV with nothing at the other end seems to be no problem (TV and CEC working fine in this case). As far as I can tell the RPi is all that changes matters here. If the RPi is not powerless (either running or being connected to the power supply) everthing works fine.

I notice the question is close to [Pi seems to prevent DVD player from switching on TV automatically](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/pi-seems-to-prevent-dvd-player-from-switching-on-tv-automatically) but not answered there either.

Comment: Which version of the Pi are you using? Some versions is known to cause problems with CEC.

Comment: It's a B Rev 2 if I am not mistaken. The PCB reads "(c) 2011.12" and "Made in the UK".

Comment: Do you have the 8-pin P5 header? How many diodes do you have on the reverse of the board at where the HDMI socket is?

Comment: 3 diodes are on the bottom side near the HDMI socket and P5 is not mounted (though the holes are there).

Comment: All three of the diodes D14-D16 populated? That means yours is an older version which have that CEC-preventing bug. You may want to buy a new one that does not have D15 and D16.

Comment: Well, although there are the B+ available and even the BananaPi I am inclined to say that I do not want to buy a new one. This is a hackers community, is it not ;) So why not hack this board to make it work? Do you have any additional information on the topic, e.g. if removing those diodes would make it work or not?

Comment: You can try remove the offending diodes and see if that works.

Comment: I have compared the schematics of Type B and Type B Rev 2 (as available on http://www.raspberrypi.org/ ) and both designs show the diodes D14 through D16. Only change being connected to 3V3 or 5V. http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=14273&start=50 also suggests removing D14 to "solve" the problem but recognizes it's a dirty hack.

Comment: Maybe you can try that.

Comment: I am checking other possibilities as people report issues with this hack... will report about the progress.